# This limit of the hypergeometric function makes me stunning...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, special-functions

I am currently reading this paper [Physics paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.3264v2.pdf)

please have a look at the definition of (20) and then (36). In (36) they investigate the limit of the hypergeometric function $_2F_1(\alpha,\beta;\gamma;\xi)$ for $\xi \rightarrow - \infty$ and they argue to get an actual result. I mean how is this possible?

I always thought that this function is only defined for $|\xi| \le 1$ like here [enter link description here](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/02/01/)

Comment: The are analytic continuations. For $\xi < - 1$ you can use the appropriate case of a linear transformation, see http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8 (formula 15.8.1)

Comment: The hyper-geometric functions originate as solutions to the hyper-geometric differential equation $$z(1-z)\frac{d^2w}{dz^2} + (\gamma - (\alpha+\beta+1)z)\frac{dw}{dz} -\alpha\beta w = 0$$ The series expansion one usually see for $_2F_1(\alpha,\beta;\gamma;z)$ is really a series expansion instead of its true definition.

Comment: thanks to both of you, I see...